# Number of equations needed to determine set of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the set of all binary functions on $\{0,1\}$. An equation like $xy=yx$ determines the subset of all commutative binary functions. For any subset of the set of all binary functions on $\{0,1\}$, can I always find an equation that characterizes that subset? And if not, what is the minimum number $k$ of equations such that their conjunction can determine any subset?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that any set of equations would be defined by a set of identities. For example, if one does not allow constants, then the constant function $1$ is indistinguishable from the consant function $0$. If one allows constants, the situation is, of course, more complicated, although I would still expect that e.g. a set of all operation except one would not be definable by identities.